# Null pointer exception when comparing two Strings

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, equals

I keep getting a Null Pointer Esception when comparing two Strings. I know both of the Strings aren't null so I am not sure what is going on.

```
public void search() {
    while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
        currState = openList.removeFirst();


        if (currState.equals(goal)) { //this line produces NullPointerException
            solution = true;
            printSolution(currState);
            break;
```

Goal is a String that I read in from a file.
Openlist is a linked list.

the string start is: 120345678
and goal is: 012345678

```
public class BFS {

public String start;
public String goal;
public String startFinal;

LinkedList<String> openList;

Map<String, Integer> levelDepth;

Map<String, String> stateHistory;

int nodes = 0;
int limit = 100;
int unique = -1;
int newValue;
int a;

public String currState;
boolean solution = false;

public BFS() {
    openList = new LinkedList<String>();
    levelDepth = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    stateHistory = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.start = start;
    this.goal = goal;
    addToOpenList(start, null);// add root

}

public void loadStartState(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    try {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();

        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder();

        while (line != null) {
            currentLine.delete(0, currentLine.capacity());
            currentLine.append(line);
            currentLine.deleteCharAt(1);
            currentLine.deleteCharAt(2);

            sb.append(currentLine.toString());
            sb.append("\n");

            line = reader.readLine();

        }
        start = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(start);

    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}

public void loadGoalState(String filename)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    try {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();

        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder();

        while (line != null) {
            currentLine.delete(0, currentLine.capacity());
            currentLine.append(line);
            currentLine.deleteCharAt(1);
            currentLine.deleteCharAt(2);

            sb.append(currentLine.toString());
            sb.append("\n");

            line = reader.readLine();

        }
        goal = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(goal);


    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

}

public void search() {
    while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
        currState = openList.removeFirst();


        if (currState != null && currState.equals(goal)) { 
            solution = true;
            printSolution(currState);
            break;

        } else {
            a = currState.indexOf("0");

            // left
            while (a != 0 && a != 3 && a != 6) {

                String nextState = currState.substring(0, a - 1) + "0"
                        + currState.charAt(a - 1)
                        + currState.substring(a + 1);
                addToOpenList(nextState, currState);
                nodes++;
                break;
            }
            // up
            while (a != 0 && a != 1 && a != 2) {

                String nextState = currState.substring(0, a - 3) + "0"
                        + currState.substring(a - 2, a)
                        + currState.charAt(a - 3)
                        + currState.substring(a + 1);
                addToOpenList(nextState, currState);
                nodes++;
                break;
            }
            // right
            while (a != 2 && a != 5 && a != 8) {

                String nextState = currState.substring(0, a)
                        + currState.charAt(a + 1) + "0"
                        + currState.substring(a + 2)
                        + currState.substring(a + 1);
                addToOpenList(nextState, currState);
                nodes++;
                break;
            }
            // down
            while (a != 6 && a != 7 && a != 8) {

                String nextState = currState.substring(0, a)
                        + currState.substring(a + 3, a + 4)
                        + currState.substring(a + 1, a + 3) + "0"
                        + currState.substring(a + 4);
                addToOpenList(nextState, currState);
                nodes++;
                break;
            }

        }

    }



}

private void addToOpenList(String newState, String oldState) {
    if (!levelDepth.containsKey(newState)) {
        newValue = oldState == null ? 0 : levelDepth.get(oldState) + 1;
        unique++;
        levelDepth.put(newState, newValue);
        openList.add(newState);
        stateHistory.put(newState, oldState);

    }

}
```

Comment: 100% `currState` is `null`, why? I don't know from the code you've posted.

Comment: _I know both of the Strings aren't null so I am not sure what is going on._ I don't believe you.

Comment: `currState` IS `null`, probably because `openList`'s first element is `null`. Definitely check `currState` ;)

Comment: Open lists first element shouldn't be null because it contains the string start?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I added the rest of my code. Maybe I was a bit rash when saying " I know it is not null".

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis maybe I don't Know they aren't null, but I can't see why they should be null?

Comment: @MariuszS It is originally initialized to null at the top of the class, but then it is made equal to the first node in the open list in the search() method.

Comment: Ok but after `addToOpenList(start, null);` the  `openList.removeFirst();` is `null`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Try this, remove invocation of `addToOpenList(start, null)` before loading value of `goal` and `start`.

### Old stuff

Here is null

```
addToOpenList(start, null);

String currState = openList.removeFirst();

currState == null
```

Additional information

```
public BFS() {
    this.start = start;  //  Variable 'start' is assigned to itself 
    this.goal = goal;    //  Variable 'goal' is assigned to itself 

    addToOpenList(start, null);   // start is null
}
```

Even my `IntelliJ` see this :)

> Method invocation currState.indexOf("0") at line 115 may produce
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

```
115:  a = currState.indexOf("0");
```

Comment: Or, assuming `goal` isn't null (which presumably it isn't), `goal.equals(currState)`. Or even `Objects.equals(currState, goal)`

Comment: I still don't understand why addToOpenList(start, null); makes currState null. The second argument of addToOpenList is the oldState which is null at the start. Why does that make start null as well?

Comment: And why does the while statement not loop?

Comment: This is another question :) Get focus on this question :)

Comment: @MariuszS I can't figure out why you think the while statement doesn't loop. I think the problem lies with the load methods because when I enter the Strings "start" and "goal" myself instead of using the load methods the program works.

Comment: Maybe because this `addToOpenList(start, null);` is invoked before load methods?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like:

```
public void search(){
    currState = openList.removeFirst();
    while(currState != null){
        if(currState.equals(goal)){
            solution = true;
            printSolution(currState);
            break;
        }
        currState = openList.removeFirst();
    }
}
```